How to deploy local langflow bot?

if you have worked with langflow, then you might have used this local interface provided by langflow but the problem is, it works only when you are running the langflow server locally, how can I use this interface without running langflow locally?

how can I change this URL to use the cloud version of langflow on the datastax instead of running langflow locally?
I tried using the datastax url of the flow but that did not seem to work.
